# How to terminate application called from bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to call some application from script. I use an application which doesn't allow any parameters in CLI but I need to test it in two different monitors and screen resolutions so I have two different configuration files. To call needed version I use simple script (name it `notebook.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

rm /home/user/.app/config.ini
cp /home/user/.app/config.ini.1366x768 /home/user/.app/config.ini
sleep 1
/usr/local/bin/app &
```

or second version with `cp` line changed.

OK, it's simple. But when I quit this app (Ctrl+Q built-in function) it still runs. Calling `ps` command I see `app` and `notebook.sh` in processes list.

My question is: how should `notebook.sh` script be written to terminate/kill `app` and script totally? Something like this piece of code:

```
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then /usr/bin/mplayer -fs -osdlevel 0 $2 ; fi
if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then killall mplayer ; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I offer you a simpler but uglier solution. :-)
You can kill a process after an amount of time with a package called `timelimit`:

```
sudo apt-get install timelimit
```

(on a terminal)

The -t option of timelimit is the number of seconds a process will stay alive: after that it will be killed (brutally) with the SIGKILL signal (if you did not specify other signals with the -S option).

```
timelimit OPTIONS command arguments
```

Edit: IF you want to use a "professional" solution, use `trap`:

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
```

It will execute the command in the commas after the "EXIT" signal.
To test it:`trap "yes test" EXIT ... then use the exit command. Bye.`

Comment: Thank you. 'Trap' command was exactly what I need but 'timelimit' is also interesting for other things.